# How to place SQLite data in TextViews when a user logs in using SQLite Database?

Tags: android

**My goal**

Step 1: User registers a new account into SQLite Database

Step 2: User logs in and goes to their Profile

Step 3: Name, Address, and Email user entered in registration get dynamically put into the appropriate TextViews.

The problem is I can only get the email to display since I am just storing that email from the Login EditText into an intent.  But I am unable to display the Name and Address of the user that they entered when they registered to be display as well in their profile when they sign in.

I have tried to use:

```
String NameHolder = intent.getStringExtra(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_1_Name);
tvName.setText(NameHolder);
```

But that doesn't display anything in the `tvName` TextView.

**Profile.java**

```
    public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    String NameHolder, EmailHolder, AddressHolder;
    Button bPicButton, bSendToPharmacy, bLogout;
    ImageView imageView;
    String pathToFile;
    TextView tvName, tvAddress, tvEmail;
    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        bPicButton = findViewById(R.id.bTakePhoto);
        bSendToPharmacy = findViewById(R.id.bSendToPharm);
        bLogout = findViewById(R.id.bLogout);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imagePrescription);

        tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvAddress = findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        tvEmail = findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);

        // Dynamically place Name, Address, and Email into TextViews
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        EmailHolder = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.UserEmail);

        displayInfo();


        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        // Ask for permission for Camera and Storage
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // if camera successfully pops up and takes photo, set photo in ImageView
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }

        // If Image was successfully placed in imageView, display submit to pharmacy button
        if (imageView != null){
            bSendToPharmacy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    // Take Picture button onClick listener
    public void takePhoto(View view) {

        setPhotoTaken();

    }

    // Take photo
    private void setPhotoTaken() {

        Intent takePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // Make sure the app can handle our intent
        if (takePhoto.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            File photoFile = null;

            // Created Photo file
            photoFile = createPhotoFile();

            // Get path of our photo file
            if (photoFile != null) {

                pathToFile = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Profile.this, "com.cognizant.expressprescriptionregistration.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePhoto, 1);
            }


        }

    }

    // Create the file where the photo will be stored
    private File createPhotoFile() {

        // Name of file
        String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        // Location of storage
        File storedDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File photo = null;

        try {

            // Creates file in storedDir
            photo = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg", storedDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photo;
    }

    // Send to Pharmacy Button
    public void sendToPharmacy(View view) {

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            String name = tvName.getText().toString();
            String message = "You have arrived at your pick up location.";

            android.app.Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentTitle(name)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(bitmap)
                            .bigLargeIcon(null))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentTitle("GeoFence Demo")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);


            openSuccessActivity();
    }

    // Method to open Register Activity
    private void openSuccessActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Success.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Prescription History DialogWindow
    public void prescriptionHistory(View view) {

        prescriptionHistoryDialogWindow();

    }

    private void prescriptionHistoryDialogWindow() {

        PrescriptionHistoryDW helpDialog = new PrescriptionHistoryDW();
        helpDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Prescription History");

    }

    // Patient Health Condition DialogWindow
    public void patientHealthCondition(View view) {

        patientHealthConditionDialogWindow();

    }

    private void patientHealthConditionDialogWindow() {

        PatientHealthConditionDW helpDialog = new PatientHealthConditionDW();
        helpDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Patient Health Description");

    }

    // Insurance Plan Details DialogWindow
    public void insurancePlanDetails(View view) {

        insurancePlanDetailsDialogWindow();

    }

    private void insurancePlanDetailsDialogWindow() {

        InsurancePlanDetailsDW helpDialog = new InsurancePlanDetailsDW();
        helpDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Insurance Plan Details");

    }

    // Logout button
    public void bLogout(View view) {

        finish();
        Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Logged out.  See you soon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

public void displayInfo() {

        sqLiteDatabaseObj = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabaseObj.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"WHERE " + Table_Column_2_Email + " = '" + EmailHolder + "'"}, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            tvEmail.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_2_Email)));
            tvName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_1_Name)));
            tvAddress.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Address)));
        }
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static final String UserEmail = "";

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // EditText Field where user puts email address to login
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

       }

        emailHolder = etEmail.getText().toString();

        // Going to Profile activity after login success message.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);

        // Send Email to Profile Activity using intent.
        intent.putExtra(UserEmail, emailHolder);

        startActivity(intent);

      }
```

**SQLiteHelper.java**

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static String DATABASE_NAME="UserDataBase";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME="UserTable";

    public static final String Table_Column_ID="id";

    public static final String Table_Column_1_Name="name";

    public static final String Table_Column_2_Email="email";

    public static final String Table_Column_3_Password="password";

    public static final String Table_Column_4_Address="address";

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+Table_Column_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+Table_Column_1_Name+" VARCHAR, "+Table_Column_2_Email+" VARCHAR, "+Table_Column_3_Password+" VARCHAR, "+Table_Column_4_Address+" VARCHAR)";
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

     }
```

**Register.java**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button bRegister;
    EditText etName, etAddress, etEmail, etPassword, etPrescriptionHistory, etPatientHealthCondition, etInsurancePlanDetails;
    String NameHolder, EmailHolder, PasswordHolder, AddressHolder;
    Boolean EditTextEmptyHolder;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabaseObj;
    String SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder ;
    SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    String F_Result = "Not_Found";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        bRegister = findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        // EditText fields
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAddress = findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        etPrescriptionHistory = findViewById(R.id.etPrescriptionHistory);
        etPatientHealthCondition = findViewById(R.id.etPatientHealthCondition);
        etInsurancePlanDetails = findViewById(R.id.etInsurancePlanDetails);

        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);

    }

    // Register Button
    public void registerButton(View view) {

//        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
//        startActivity(intent);

        // Create SQlite Database if it doesn't exist
        SQLiteDataBaseBuild();

        // Create SQLite Table if it doesn't exist
        SQLiteTableBuild();

        // Make sure no EditText field is empty
        CheckEditTextStatus();

        // Make sure email has not already been registered
        CheckingEmailAlreadyExistsOrNot();

        // Empty all EditText fields after successful database entry
        EmptyEditTextAfterDataInsert();


    }

    // SQLite database build method.
    public void SQLiteDataBaseBuild(){

        sqLiteDatabaseObj = openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    }

    // SQLite table build method.
    public void SQLiteTableBuild() {

        sqLiteDatabaseObj.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + "(" + SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_ID + " PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " + SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_1_Name + " VARCHAR, " + SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_2_Email + " VARCHAR, " + SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_3_Password + " VARCHAR, " + SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Address + " VARCHAR);");

    }

    // Insert data into SQLite database method.
    public void InsertDataIntoSQLiteDatabase(){

        // If editText is not empty then this block will executed.
        if(EditTextEmptyHolder == true)
        {

            // SQLite query to insert data into table.
            SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder = "INSERT INTO "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+" (name,email,password, address) VALUES('"+NameHolder+"', '"+EmailHolder+"', '"+PasswordHolder+"', '"+AddressHolder+"');";

            // Executing query.
            sqLiteDatabaseObj.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder);

            // Closing SQLite database object.
            sqLiteDatabaseObj.close();

            // Message if successful
            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        // If any EditText fields are empty, prevent user from creating profile
        else {

            // Message if any EditText fields are empty
            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Please Make Sure All Fields are filled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    // Empty edittext after done inserting process method.
    public void EmptyEditTextAfterDataInsert(){

        etName.getText().clear();

        etEmail.getText().clear();

        etPassword.getText().clear();

        etAddress.getText().clear();

    }

    // Method to check EditText is empty or Not.
    public void CheckEditTextStatus(){

        // Getting value from All EditText and storing into String Variables.
        NameHolder = etName.getText().toString() ;
        EmailHolder = etEmail.getText().toString();
        PasswordHolder = etPassword.getText().toString();
        AddressHolder = etAddress.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(NameHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder)){

            EditTextEmptyHolder = false ;

        }
        else {

            EditTextEmptyHolder = true ;
        }
    }

    // Checking Email is already exists or not.
    public void CheckingEmailAlreadyExistsOrNot(){

        // Opening SQLite database write permission.
        sqLiteDatabaseObj = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Adding search email query to cursor.
        cursor = sqLiteDatabaseObj.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, " " + SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_2_Email + "=?", new String[]{EmailHolder}, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            if (cursor.isFirst()) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                // If email is already created, set error
                F_Result = "Email already registered";

                // Closing cursor.
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        // Calling method to check final result and insert data into SQLite database.
        CheckFinalResult();

    }


    // Checking result
    public void CheckFinalResult(){

        // Checking whether email is already exists or not.
        if(F_Result.equalsIgnoreCase("Email already registered"))
        {

            // If email is exists then toast msg will display.
            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Email already registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else {

            // If email is not already in the database, it will be created in the database
            InsertDataIntoSQLiteDatabase();

        }

        F_Result = "Not_Found" ;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share more of the relevant code? Where is the code that sends the intent you are receiving in the above code?

Comment: Added more code.

Comment: Your issue is you are trying to pull the data from the intent which simply won't work because you never put it into the intent. You either need to put the data you want to display into the intent OR from profile.java use the email address you get from the intent to pull the information from the database and then display it.

Comment: "from profile.java use the email address you get from the intent to pull the information from the database and then display it"  Correct.  This is where I am stuck.  I went through guides online and they all just show how to display the email or username the user enters into the login screen, which is easy.  But I can't figure out how to display the other info that the user input when they registered and put that data into the TextViews of their Profile screen after they login.

Comment: You need a method in your SQLiteHelper class that can take that email address and query the database for the other information and return it to whoever called the method (profile.java in your case).

Comment: That makes sense.  Do you have an example please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195141/discussion-between-treewallie-and-ck1221).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking after your code, It seems you are not saving the data in the actual Database. 
But passing them from one Activity to another.

I would suggest you go through [this training](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to learn how to save data with Room.

Let me know if you face any trouble in understanding. I can point you out in the right direction.

If you are sure you are storing the data correctly.

Create sqLiteDatabaseObj instance how you have created in Register Activity and then Below method will set the user details. Call this method in OnCreate at the end of it.

```
    public void displayInfo() {

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabaseObj.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE "+Table_Column_2_Email +" = '"+EmailHolder +"'", null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        tvEmail.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_2_Email)));
                      tvName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_1_Name)));

       tvAddress.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_4_Address)));
               }
               if(cursor != null) {
                   cursor.close();
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a bit inefficient and will not work if you allow multiple users to log on from the same device. Your query should include a where clause that uses the login email to get the rest of the data and the do...while loop should just not exist.

Comment: @ck1221 Do you have an example code?  I am running into an issue now where it will not load the data of the user that logs in and instead only shows the data of the last person who registered.

Comment: Start by removing the do...while loop. That is what is causing you to get the last person who registered and won't be needed when you add the where clause. It looks like the answer has been modified to include the where clause so take a look a query again.